# Using MATLAB's diary function in an executable (MATLAB Application Compliler Toolbox)

Tags: matlab

I've created a code that will be run as an executable.  However, the running of an executable has an error that doesn't exist in the MATLAB scripts.  Trying to document this, I ran across the "diary" command which seems like an appropriate way of logging the error.  Command: `diary('LogFile.txt')`

However, when running the compiled version, I immediately get a pop up error: **LogFile.txt: Cannot open file: permission denied.**

I'm getting a bit flummuxed as it appears to be having trouble writing to its own folder.  Should I be trying to store to C:\Users, or is there some other glitch I'm running into?

Comment: Typical location for logfiles on windows OS is a subfolder of `getenv('appdata')`. Try it, writing should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to 'Daniel' for his suggestion of `getenv('appdata')`.  I would add that my path was ..\AppData\Roaming\ so I would suggest a way of viewing the location of the log file in your gui just to be sure you can find (or that others using your app can find it).  Thanks!